# Erro ao tentar executar emulador android sem o android studio

Tags: android, android-layout, sdk, avd

Instalei o android studio e estudei como utilizar o avd sem a necessidade do android studio, aprendi como fazer as maquinas via linha de comando e funcionou perfeitamente, mas quando eu fui em outra maquina e baixei o sdk e executei os mesmo comandos a maquina não é criada e apresenta este erro:

```
avdmanager create avd -n whatsapp -k "system-images;android-24;google_apis_playstore;x86"
Error: Invalid --tag default for the selected package.
```

Imagens instaladas:

```
Valid system image paths are:
system-images;android-24;google_apis;armeabi-v7a
system-images;android-24;google_apis_playstore;x86
system-images;android-22;google_apis;x86
```

Recursos instalados:

```
sdkmanager.bat --list
Installed packages:
  Path                              | Version | Description                       | Location
  -------                           | ------- | -------                           | -------
  build-tools;26.0.1                | 26.0.1  | Android SDK Build-Tools 26.0.1    | build-tools\26.0.1\
  emulator                          | 26.1.4  | Android Emulator                  | emulator\
  extras;android;m2repository       | 47.0.0  | Android Support Repository        | extras\android\m2repository\
  extras;google;m2repository        | 58      | Google Repository                 | extras\google\m2repository\
  extras;intel;Ha...ecution_Manager | 6.2.1   | Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator... | extras\intel\Ha...cution_Manager\
  extras;m2reposi...ut-solver;1.0.2 | 1       | Solver for ConstraintLayout 1.0.2 | extras\m2reposi...t-solver\1.0.2\
  extras;m2reposi...nt-layout;1.0.2 | 1       | ConstraintLayout for Android 1... | extras\m2reposi...t-layout\1.0.2\
  patcher;v4                        | 1       | SDK Patch Applier v4              | patcher\v4\
  platform-tools                    | 26.0.0  | Android SDK Platform-Tools        | platform-tools\
  platforms;android-22              | 2       | Android SDK Platform 22           | platforms\android-22\
  platforms;android-26              | 2       | Android SDK Platform 26           | platforms\android-26\
  sources;android-24                | 1       | Sources for Android 24            | sources\android-24\
  sources;android-25                | 1       | Sources for Android 25            | sources\android-25\
  system-images;a...google_apis;x86 | 17      | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom Sys... | system-images\a...oogle_apis\x86\
  system-images;a...pis;armeabi-v7a | 17      | Google APIs ARM EABI v7a Syste... | system-images\a...is\armeabi-v7a\
  system-images;a...s_playstore;x86 | 16      | Google Play Intel x86 Atom Sys... | system-images\a..._playstore\x86\
  tools                             | 26.0.1  | Android SDK Tools 26.0.1          | tools\
```

Estes aqui são os recursos da maquina que instalei o android studio e o emulador funciona normalmente:

```
sdkmanager.bat --list
Installed packages:
  Path                              | Version | Description                       | Location
  -------                           | ------- | -------                           | -------
  build-tools;26.0.1                | 26.0.1  | Android SDK Build-Tools 26.0.1    | build-tools\26.0.1\
  emulator                          | 26.1.4  | Android Emulator                  | emulator\
  extras;android;m2repository       | 47.0.0  | Android Support Repository        | extras\android\m2repository\
  extras;google;m2repository        | 58      | Google Repository                 | extras\google\m2repository\
  extras;intel;Ha...ecution_Manager | 6.2.1   | Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator... | extras\intel\Ha...cution_Manager\
  extras;m2reposi...ut-solver;1.0.2 | 1       | Solver for ConstraintLayout 1.0.2 | extras\m2reposi...t-solver\1.0.2\
  extras;m2reposi...nt-layout;1.0.2 | 1       | ConstraintLayout for Android 1... | extras\m2reposi...t-layout\1.0.2\
  patcher;v4                        | 1       | SDK Patch Applier v4              | patcher\v4\
  platform-tools                    | 26.0.0  | Android SDK Platform-Tools        | platform-tools\
  platforms;android-22              | 2       | Android SDK Platform 22           | platforms\android-22\
  platforms;android-26              | 2       | Android SDK Platform 26           | platforms\android-26\
  system-images;a...google_apis;x86 | 16      | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom Sys... | system-images\a...oogle_apis\x86\
  system-images;a...s_playstore;x86 | 16      | Google Play Intel x86 Atom Sys... | system-images\a..._playstore\x86\
  tools                             | 26.0.2  | Android SDK Tools                 | tools\
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estava utilizando duas pastas com sdk, ao deletar uma delas tudo voltou a funcionar normalmente.